# How can I create and define a SKSpriteNode in a different class and access it? Xcode 6 :)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

I was wondering how I could create a SKSpriteNode in a class and use it and add it in another class. I tried using @property, but I probably used it wrong. Could someone please help? :0

Thanks!!

EDIT:

I pretty much just created a property like this:

> `@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *testNode;`

and in the other class which is GameScene I imported the class with the property and tried to type in testNode to try and change it's properties but nothing popped up. I even tried 'testClass.testNode' or 'self.testNode'.

testClass.h ---

> ```
> @interface testClass : SKScene
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *testNode;
>
> @end
> ```

GameScene.m ---

> -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
>       /* Setup your scene here */
>
> ```
> testNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Character"];
> ```
>
> }

GameScene.h ---

> ```
> #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
> #import "testClass.h"
>
> @interface GameScene : SKScene{
>
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: can you please show us your code?

Comment: sure. It was pretty basic and hoped I explained well. @rakeshbs

Comment: was `testClass` was the instance of your custom class? Can you show the whole class definition and the place where you try to call the property

Comment: Ok, I added testClass.h, GameScene.m, and GameScene.h. Hoped it helps! @rakeshbs

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class which inherits from SKSpriteNode and instantiate it in your scene:

```
import SpriteKit

class MyNode: SKSpriteNode {
    override init() {

    }
}
```

And later:

```
let myNode = MyNode()
```

Here's the Swift guide about inheritance:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID193

Comment: I'm doing this in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

In GameScene, first initialize the other class:

testClass *testClassInstance = [[testClass alloc] initWithSize:self.size]];

Then, get the property:

testClassInstance.testNode